# WebSphere Portal API for getting URL without Navigation State

Tags: navigation, websphere-portal, spi

I have below piece of code to get the WebSphere Portal URL from portal page uniquename. But the generated URL is having navigation state details also which I don't need. I need the URL without any state information. Please help in this. Thanks in Advance!!

```
URLFactory urlFactory = null;
    SelectionAccessorController selCtrl = null;
    PortletServiceHome serviceHome = null;
    Context ctx = null;
    try {
        ctx = new InitialContext();
        serviceHome = (PortletServiceHome) ctx.lookup("portletservice/com.ibm.portal.state.service.PortletStateManagerService");
        PortletStateManagerService service =
                (PortletStateManagerService) serviceHome
                        .getPortletService(PortletStateManagerService.class);

        try {
            PortletStateManager manager = service.getPortletStateManager(request, response);
            urlFactory = manager.getURLFactory();
            EngineURL url = urlFactory.newURL(Constants.EMPTY_COPY);
            com.ibm.portal.state.accessors.selection.SelectionAccessorFactory selFct =
                    (com.ibm.portal.state.accessors.selection.SelectionAccessorFactory) manager
                            .getAccessorFactory(com.ibm.portal.state.accessors.selection.SelectionAccessorFactory.class);
            selCtrl = selFct.getSelectionAccessorController(url.getState());
            selCtrl.setSelection(uniqueName);
            return url.writeDispose(new StringWriter()).toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e;
        } finally {
            if (null != selCtrl)
                selCtrl.dispose();
            if (null != urlFactory)
                urlFactory.dispose();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (null != selCtrl)
            selCtrl.dispose();
        if (null != urlFactory)
            urlFactory.dispose();
    }
    return null;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using EngineUrl try using FriendlyUrl to generate the Url.

```
FriendlyURL url=urlFactory.newURL(Constants.EMPTY_COPY);
url.setSelection("ibm.portal.Home");
url.dispose();
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and worked with a short URL :

EngineURL url = urlFactory.newURL(Constants.DEEP_COPY);

I used Constants.DEEP_COPY instead of Constants.EMPTY_COPY